# VS Code indent width 4, but still have tab width 8, how?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editorconfig

I have an old code base that uses a weird indentation style. It uses tab width 8, but indents 4 notches, replacing 8 spaces by tabs where possible.

Code should look like this:

```
____if (foo) {
TAB---->if (bar) {
TAB---->____something();
TAB---->}
____}
```

I have installed the *EditorConfig for Visual Studio Code* extension and my `.editorconfig` has this:

```
root = true

[*]
insert_final_newline = true
indent_size = 4
tab_width = 8
```

But the existing code looks like this:

```
____if (foo) {
TAB>if (bar) {
TAB>____something();
TAB>}
____}
```

When I add `indent_style = tab`, the existing code looks correct again, but when I type new code, I get this:

```
____if (foo) {   // after hitting Enter on this line the next line is indented too far:
TAB---->____something
____}
```

How can I achieve the desired display and indentation behavior?

Comment: This should be a question for Superuser, not Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug / missing feature in VSCode itself: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/10339

Comment: Wow, this is quick, thanks. There is a limitation on Stack Overflow side that I cannot award the bounty right now. At least one day must pass.

Comment: After reading the issue at Github, I'm not sure whether those who want the feature mean the same thing that I mean: that a tab character is used when the indentation is 8 or more places. I think they mean to use only spaces for indentation even though it is never spelled out explicitly in this way.

Comment: You're right that the bug is only the first step for achieving what you want (the desired display behavior). For the second part (replacing 8 spaces with the tab character) one could easily write a plugin once the display bug is fixed.

Comment: changing `"editor.indentSize": "tabSize"` to `"editor.indentSize": 4` solved the issue for me, though it's not the good solution!